# convert base64 encoded png pic using PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library

all. Recently I am using PIL to complete some code. As a default demo shows me how to convert a jpg picture file like this:

```
img = Image.open(filePath).convert('RGB')
```

Then I also try to convert a base64 encoded picture to finish the same thing. The only difference is the picture is obtained from url which is base64 encoded.

```
codec = 'base64 encoded picture'
base64_data = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', codec)
byte_data = base64.b64decode(base64_data)
image_data = BytesIO(byte_data)
img = Image.open(image_data)
img = img.convert('RGB')
```

which shows "broken stream whille reading the picture" at the and of the last line. Is there any thing I misunderstand??

Answer (score 0):

For some debugging work, I find that python2 and python3 use different lib(IOString and ByteIO). Just make a mismatch and correct it will make this code work.